# AngularJS ng-options from an object with objects

Tags: angularjs, object, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am attempting to have my data show up in the list as follows:

```
<option value="4351">Atlanta</option>
```

Here is my object.

```
$scope.cityList = {
    4351:{name:"Atlanta", short="atlanta"},
    7355:{name:"Baltimore", short="baltimore"},
    1212:{name:"Chicago", short="chicago"},
    4398:{name:"Dallas", short="dallas"}
};
```

HTML
This worked with just key-value pairs, but now the "value" is an object

```
<select class="select-city" ng-model="myCity" ng-options="name for (city, name) in cityList"></select>
```

So my question is this:
How can I populate the ng-options in this case?

Comment: `name.name for (city, name) in cityList`?

Comment: Thanks, that totally works! Can you explain how and I'll accept your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `name.name for (city, name) in cityList` - the `name.name` in this case refers to the `name` property of the new object you introduced, which itself is unfortunately named `name`.

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) is a bit mystic but you can perhaps also rename it to something like `value.name for (key, value) in cityList`.

Comment: Name is named name? Funny, nevername me